# How to use WebGL to render a button background?

Tags: html, webgl

Let's say that I have a GL shader I'd want to use as an HTML `button` background (it's a pretty animated gradient). How can I achieve that?

I can think of setting the background to a texture and rendering the shader to this texture. Is that fundamentally possible?

Comment: This might be possible but it seems like incredible overkill. There's a good chance the same thing could be achieved with just CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `canvas` inside a button is the most logical way to go, note that this is just an example and not a shader, but we use the canvas to render WebGL so it can be slightly different for your case.

```js
var c = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "green");
// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
}

button > div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button>
   <canvas></canvas>
   <div>Fancy Button</div>
</button>
```